# Python: threads using join() in while loop

Tags: python, join, while-loop, block, python-multithreading

I would like my while loop to block at most 5 seconds for all threads it creates in the for loop. However, the following code will block by the threads one by one. How can I approach my goal? Thanks.

```
threads = []
while True:
    for 3:
        newThread = threading.Thread(..)
        threads.append(newThread)
        newThread.start()
        newThread.join(5)
```

Comment: What you are searching is pthread analogue of `WaitForMultipleObjects` from Windows.  It may helps to find solution in the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use condition variable (`threading.Condition` in Python).  It allows to wait for a predicate to become true.  In your case the predicate is `all threads have finished work or time out exceeded`.  Here is code which creates ten threads and waits until they are finished with 5sec time out.  Verbose logs will help you:

```
import threading
import time
import logging


logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(threadName)s:%(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)


NUM_OF_THREADS = 10
TIMEOUT = 5


def sleeping_thread(delay, cond):
    logging.debug("Hi, I'm going to delay by %d sec." % delay)
    time.sleep(delay)
    logging.debug("I was sleeping for %d sec." % delay)
    cond.acquire()
    logging.debug("Calling notify().")
    cond.notify()
    cond.release()


def create_sleeping_thread(delay, cond):
    return threading.Thread(target=sleeping_thread,
                            args=(delay, cond))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cond = threading.Condition(threading.Lock())
    cond.acquire()

    working_counter = NUM_OF_THREADS
    for i in xrange(NUM_OF_THREADS):
        t = create_sleeping_thread(i, cond)
        t.start()

    start_time = time.time()
    while working_counter > 0 and (time.time() - start_time < TIMEOUT):
        cond.wait()
        working_counter -= 1
        logging.debug('%d workers still working', working_counter)
    cond.release()
    logging.debug('Finish waiting for threads (%d workers still working)',
                 working_counter)
```

Further information at [comp.programming.threads FAQ](http://www.lambdacs.com/cpt/FAQ.html#Q292).

Answer (score 2):

One thing to do is start all the threads, and then iterate over the array and join. But I suppose, this would still wait up to a total of 5*thread count seconds. Alternatively, you could create one additional thread that simply waits for your threads indefinitely. Then in your main thread you can just wait for the extra thread for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to spawn a thread every 5 seconds, except if one of the already-running threads ends, you wish to spawn a new thread sooner? If so, you could use a `threading.Event` to signal when a worker thread ends, and use `event.wait(timeout)` to block at most 5 seconds for the event:

```
import threading
import time
import logging

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

def foo_event(n,e):
    time.sleep(n)
    name=threading.current_thread().name
    logger.info('{n}: setting event'.format(n=name))
    e.set()

def main():
    e=threading.Event()
    threads=[]
    N=5
    for i in range(3):
        t=threading.Thread(target=foo_event,args=(N+1,e,),name='worker-{i}'.format(i=i))
        threads.append(t)
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()
        logger.info('entering wait')
        e.wait(N)
        logger.info('exit wait')
        e.clear()

main()
```

yields

```
05:06:34: entering wait
05:06:39: exit wait                 <-- Wait 5 seconds
05:06:39: entering wait
05:06:40: worker-0: setting event   
05:06:40: exit wait                 <-- Wait <5 seconds
05:06:40: entering wait
05:06:45: worker-1: setting event
05:06:45: exit wait                 <-- Wait 5 seconds
```

Comment: The sooner the better. By your approach, the worker-1 have to wait for the worker-0 right? But that's not what I want. I expect the five threads finish as soon as possible.